# Husky needs to make executable for every new branch

Tags: pre-commit, husky

If [husky hook is not running](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=hooks-not-running), we need to execute command `chmod +x .husky/*`. **But I need to run `chmod +x .husky/*` every time I go to a new branch.** Otherwise, it shows this error:

> hint: The '.husky/pre-commit' hook was ignored because it's not set as
> executable.

Can anybody tell me how can I solve this issue?

I am using husky 7.0.1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got my solution. I added `pre-commit` file manually so it was not executable(644). I removed **pre-commit** file and added using this command `yarn husky add .husky/pre-commit` that makes `pre-commit` file executable(755) and works fine any new branch.

So, to solve this type of issue, we have to avoid adding manual hook file and use this command `yarn husky add .husky/<hookname>` to add.

Comment: IDK why but I also used husky to add the pre-commit hook, but there are 2 difference here, first is that I used npx, and the second one is that I did not pass any script for the pre-commit; `npx husky add .husky/pre-commit`.

Answer (score 17):

You can also add `"prepare": "husky install && chmod ug+x .husky/*"` to your scripts in package.json to automatically set executable permissions while enabling Git hooks.

Comment: thx, how do you make that windows friendly?

Comment: you can wrap call it with bash like so:
`"prepare": "husky install && bash -c 'chmod ug+x .husky/*'"`